# glm in python vs R

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression, statsmodels

I have some dataset: titanic

Doing this in R

`glm(Survived ~ Sex, titanic, family = "binomial")`

I get

```
(Intercept)     SexMale 
1.124321   -2.477825
```

R takes **survived** as positive outcome.

But when I'm doing the same in Python

`sm.formula.glm("Survived ~ Sex", family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=titanic).fit()`

I get negative results: i.e. Python takes **not survived** as positive outcome.

How can I adjust Python's glm function behavior so it will return the same result as R does?

Comment: I doubt `sm.formula.glm` is available in base python. Please list any modules / packages that you are using in the body of your question or add the appropriate tag.

Comment: `import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd`
`import statsmodels.api as sm`

Answer (score 12):

You just need to set your reference group to either male or female (depending on what you're interested in):

With a small test dataset in R, the code and model summary looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(0,0,1,1,0), c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"))
colnames(df) <- c("Survived", "Sex")

model <- glm(Survived ~ Sex, data=df, family="binomial")
summary(model)
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -3.084e-16  1.414e+00   0.000    1.000
SexMale     -6.931e-01  1.871e+00  -0.371    0.711
```

To get something similar in Python/statsmodels:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({"Survived": [0,0,1,1,0],
                   "Sex": ["Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male"]})

model = sm.formula.glm("Survived ~ C(Sex, Treatment(reference='Female'))",
                       family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=df).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

Which will give:

```
                                                    coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                      5.551e-16      1.414   3.93e-16      1.000      -2.772       2.772
C(Sex, Treatment(reference='Female'))[T.Male]    -0.6931      1.871     -0.371      0.711      -4.360       2.974
```

Notice the use of `Treatment()` to set the reference group. I've set it to `Female` in this case to match the R output, but with your dataset it might make more sense to use `Male`. Either way, its just an issue of being explicit about which group is used as reference.